# Yii2 Email not sending if call after a DB transaction

Tags: php, database, email, yii2, swiftmailer

When I try to save a record in the database and then call the email function, email doesn't send.
Here's my code

```
    //***********my controller methods*******************
    /**
     * Save test result data in the storage and send an email
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionSaveTestResultData() {
        $data = Yii::$app->request->post('data');
        $response = $this->testResultService->saveTestResultData($data);
        $mail = $this->notificationEmailService->sendEmailNotification($response);

        return '<IOT>'.$mail.'</IOT>';

    }

    //****************My Email service*********************
    /**
     * Send emails 
     * @param $data
     * @return bool
     */
    public function sendEmailNotification($data) {

        $result = Yii::$app->mailer->compose('breach-notification', ['data' => $data])
            ->setFrom('admin@gmail.com')
            ->setTo('test@test.com')
            ->setSubject('My Subject')
            ->send();

        return $result;
    }
```

But if I directly call the email function it gets send.

```
         /**
         * Send email notification on a breach - Test function
         * @param $response
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function actionEmail($response) {
            $mail = $this->notificationEmailService->sendEmailNotification($response);
            return '<IOT>'.$mail.'</IOT>';
        }
```

I want to send the email only using the `actionSaveTestResultData()` and `sendEmailNotification($data)`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: I've edited the question. Is it still unclear?

Comment: Is the data being saved despite the email not being sent?

Comment: yes it saves as desired

Comment: Are there any debug messages shown after saving the data? Is the email function being called (but the email not being sent)?

Comment: yes function gets called. If I put a var_dump() there, I can see it. It's just the email not sending. How can I on debug mode in swiftmailer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122424/discussion-between-topher-and-gecco).